# After mod_rewrite the internal URLs are duplicated many times when crawling

Tags: mod-rewrite, links, url-rewriting, canonical-url

I'm sure it is my mistake in mod_rewrite rules, but I can't seem to figure it out. 
I've set up the rules for my new site and all works perfect, unless - I try to create a sitemap. The URLs get duplicated/triplicated/etc... pretty much ten URLs which open the same page.

Here are the rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule sport/training/article/(.*)$ ./article.php?q=$1
RewriteRule sport/eating/article/(.*)$ ./article.php?q=$1
RewriteRule sport/track/article/(.*)$ ./article.php?q=$1

RewriteRule sport/training/(.*)$ ./list.php?l=1p=$1
RewriteRule sport/eating/(.*)$ ./list.php?l=2&p=$1
RewriteRule sport/track/(.*)$ ./list.php?l=3&p=$1
```

When my site gets crawled, the result is something like this:

```
http://www.blah.com/sport/training/article/article-about-sport
http://www.blah.com/sport/training/sport/training/article/article-about-sport
```

Sometimes it is even like this:

```
http://www.blah.com/sport/training/sport/training/article/article/article-about-sport
```

All of the above open the correct page BTW.

Internal generated link structure design seems to be ok. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: I assume you are using a tool to crawl your site to create your sitemap??

Comment: Yes, an online tool. Is that bad? I tried to scan it with Xenu and it shows all that duplicate content either.

Comment: No. Normally, that would be fine. Online tools are somewhat limited in that they will spider your site and return what it sees, but with little intelligence. Some download tools are the same way. If you are using a CMS, then a plug-in could help. If you can write code, then it may be simpler depending. I wrote mine in 20 minutes but it gets it's information from a database. If your site is traditional HTML web pages then it may be best to clean-up any links you have to remove duplicates and try again. Otherwise, you can edit the file, but that could be a chore too.

Comment: It's a CMS that I wrote myself and articles get fetched from DB too. The links are "nonexistent" pretty/SEO friendly links, based on mod rewrite patterns (if it's "/article/" it forwards the friendly url to article.php which then fetches the data).

Comment: Ah ha! You can simply write code then!! It is a lot less challenging than it appears and you can put your own intel into it like I did. BTW- I wrote my own CMS(ish) kinda thing that is a relational HTML kind of short-hand which it much smaller. It is freaky weird. I replicated DMOZ with just 11 characters of content (could have been just 3 with an alias). The rest were relational references. Simple, yet allows for extensive references that can get really really wild at times!! MAJOR FUN!!! It takes a new way of thinking that is simple to learn, but crazy complicated if you want to do it right.

Comment: I fail to see how this has anything to do with .htaccess? Yes, your .htaccess would seem to permit these URLs, but if the crawler is able to find these URLs in the first place then it must be how the URLs are being generated on the page - that is after all the only thing that the crawler sees. (?)

Comment: w3d> That is why it is so weird... I can't find these quadriplicated URLs anywhere on my generated URL structure. Boggles my mind... But you give a good insight (that crawler does what it SEES. Food for thought.).

Comment: Do you have anything else in your .htaccess file? (No redirects?) How are you constructing URLs in your app? Relative, root-relative, absolute? Do these invalid URLs return a valid response?

Comment: I have another rule set RewriteRule ^sport/(.*)$ ./list_themes.php?l=1&p=$1 . It is for a whole set of a given theme (and it's underthemes) in one page (for footer menu links), but it is fetched by a separate php file as you can see so I don't think it is related. I'm constructing relative URL's "/link/etc" or "../", and htaccsess file is in httpdocs so it is always website root directory. It is probably related to this somehow, I just need to figure out how.

Comment: I just figured it out. It actually turns out to be a mistake in URL generation. If not the idea about "crawler sees what it sees" I would've gone crazy, because I was concentrating on my rewrite rules. Thank you guys!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, You can post that as an answer (and later accept it) - so the question will be taken out of the unanswered question queue.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to select it. Maybe my "rank" is too low.?

Comment: "Select" what? If you are referring to "accepting" an answer, then you need to post the answer before you can accept it. But I don't think you can accept it immediately - you will get a message notifying you of this.

Comment: I just figured it out. It actually turns out to be a mistake in URL generation. If not the idea about "crawler sees what it sees" I would've gone crazy, because I was concentrating on my rewrite rules. Thank you guys! –

Comment: Sorry, I'm still quite a noob here. Just did that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. It actually turns out to be a mistake in URL generation. It was an idea about "crawler sees what it sees" that helped me to solve this.